# Does a virus run under all profiles or only the one that "caught" it?

Tags: virus, user-profiles

My computer has the virus that tries to trick the user into buying some kind of Security software. It was installed when I was running the computer under the Administrative account.  My questions is, will this virus keep running under the profiles that do not have Admin rights?  Or do viruses run under the account that was logged in when it was installed?

Answer (score 0):

Most have full access to the machine, and in the case of rootkits most definitely so. The thing is, if you have a standard user account and picked up an infection, you know that the virus has full access because standard users aren't allowed to install software by default.

I recommend removing this piece of malware or consider reinstalling your operating system completely.

Comment: It does not seem to be running under the general user account.  I've run Norton scans which ckeaned two viruses but I only get the security screens when logged in as an Admin

Answer (score 0):

If you were running as administror when it was installed you are probably in a bad position, as the administrator account is a super account and can affect other accounts - thus without more information best practice dictates you should consider the entire machine (and all user accounts) compromised, and if you don't have faith in your AV software to clean it you should reinstall from scratch.

The point of having user accounts separate from admin accounts is to prevent regular users hosing the system for other users, but using an admin account bypasses this safeguard.